Unable to install or remove corrupted linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic
I'm trying to install and reinstall a corrupted linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic, but I keep getting errors. What am I doing wrong?
(base) kevin@linux:~$ sudo apt --purge remove linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic python3-gi-cairo
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:

dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-40-generic

Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-40-generic -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.8/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtbth-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.8/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-40-generic/x86_64 failed for rtbth(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.

dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-40-generic.....................................]

...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic (--configure):
installed linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic; however:
Package linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic
linux-headers-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
